# Vue js: Computed property not updating when changing route

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a dashboard page that when I refresh the page it works fine, I retrieved my data. However, when I go to other links and move back to my dashboard page (previous page) it doesn't update my computed `giveaways` property, it doesn't return the data anymore but in my response It still work fine it just not rendering because of my computed property. I'm using axios in my vuex, I tried also the `this.$forceUpdate` but I don't know where's the right place to do this. What I trying to make is like everytime they go that dashboard.vue page whether its via refresh or vue-route it should reupdate the computed property because I reevaluate the data from my serverside.

Here is my Dashboard.vue script

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default{
    ready(){
        this.loaded =false;

    },
    data: () => ({
        cards: [

        ],
        cards_offender:[

        ],
        //giveaways: '',

        loaded: true
    }),
    computed:{
        ...mapState({
            Giveaway: state => state.Threshold.giveaways
        }),
        ...mapGetters({
            //done : 'doneGiveaways',
            //Done : getter => getters.Threshold.doneGiveaways
        }),
        giveaways(){
            //this.$foreceUpdate();
            //this.$store.dispatch('getGiveAways');
            return this.$store.getters.doneGiveaways
        },
        testing(){
            return this.$store.getters.loadTesting
        }
    },
    watch:{
        giveaways(newVal, oldVal){
            console.log(newVal + 'test');
        },
        testing(newVal, oldval){
            console.log(newVal)
        },
        deep: true
    },
    created(){

    },
    methods:{

    },
    mounted(){
        this.$store.dispatch('getGiveAways');
        this.cards[2].result_val = this.$store.getters.doneGiveaways;
        if(this.$store.getters.doneGiveaways > 0){
            this.cards[2].background_color = 'orange';
            console.log('wew');
        }
        /*if(this.$store.state.Threshold.giveaways === null){
            this.$store.dispatch('getGiveAways');
        }else{}*/
    }
}
```

And here is my Threshold.js vuex

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);


const state = {
    giveaways: null,
    testing: ['wew']
}

const actions = {
    getGiveAways : ({commit}) =>{
        axios({
            url : '/prod/api/thresholds_settings',
            method: 'post',
            data : {
            },
            config: 'JOSN'
        })
        .then(response=>{
            if(response.status == 200){
                //console.log(response.data.total_giveaways);
                commit('SET_GIVEAWAYS', response.data.total_giveaways)
                //dispatch('getGiveAways');
            }
        })
        .catch(error=>{
            if(error.response){
                console.log('something happened')
            }
        });
    }
}

const mutations = {
    SET_GIVEAWAYS : (state, obj)=>{
        state.giveaways = obj
    }

}

const getters = {
    doneGiveaways(state){
        return state.giveaways
    },
    loadTesting(state){
        return state.testing
    }
}

export default {
    state, mutations, actions, getters
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to re-populate the data while the router changes back, then the function should be in the `created()` instead of `computed: { ... }` I believe.

Comment: @Johnson It returning null I think because the created hook fire first before the action

Comment: @Johnson its just too long to load but it works when I call the `this.giveaways` on created()

Comment: You can take a look under the lifecycle diagram to see what get's called first, but calling it from the created is correct. I'm not sure what else is going on with your code as far as why it's slow, i'd need to see it live and debug. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your match option to this:

```
watch:{
    giveaways(newVal, oldVal){
        console.log(newVal + 'test');
    },
    testing(newVal, oldval){
        console.log(newVal)
    },
    deep: true,
    $route: this.giveaways
},
```

or add this to the router file (requires another dependency - [vuex-router-store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-router-sync) )

```
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import store from './vuex/store' // vuex store instance
import router from './router' // vue-router instance
```